# Adding more existing objects to an existing Code First Entity Data Model

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

How to add objects into an existing reverse engeneered model under Code First scenario with existing database? 
Suppose I have added ADO.NET Entity Data Model -> Code first from database.
Then choose 20 tables out of say 350 from an existing database.
And later I want to pick and add to my POCO-model more tables/objects. There is no option to add another object.
I can recreate Data Model from scratch, but I'll have to choose all the tables I need, wich is obviously not convinient at all.

Comment: Try [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only semi-convenient way I've done this is by starting a new project with the same namespaces.....generate the "new" ones...then copy the .cs files over to my existing project, and copy lines of code for the mappings.

I don't think there is a "append-update" feature.

I would do the entire database (in the fake project)...and just have it "handy" for later....if you decided to bring in more items.

Sorry, its a poor-mans method, but just letting you know.